# SQLite - Exploiting Sorted Indexes

Tags: sorting, indexing, sqlite, sql-order-by

This is probably simple, but I can't find the answer.

I'm trying to minimise the overhead of selecting records using ORDER BY

My understanding is that in...

```
SELECT gorilla, chimp FROM apes ORDER BY bananas LIMIT 10;
```

...the full set of matching records is retrieved so that that the ORDER BY can be actioned, even if I only want the top ten records.  This makes sense.

Trying to eliminate that overhead, I looked at the possibility of storing the records in a pre-defined order, but that would only work until insertions/deletions took place, upon which I would have to re-build the table.  Not viable.

I found an option in SQLite (I assume it also exists in other SQLs) to create a sorted index (https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html)...

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON apes (bananas DESC);
```

...which I **ASSUME** to mean that the index (not the table) is sorted in descending order and will remain so after updates .

My question is - how do I exploit this?  The SQLite documentation is a bit meh in this regard.   Is there some kind of "SELECT FROM index" or equivalent?  Or does the fact that a sorted index exists on a column mean that any results from querying that column will be returned in the order of the index rather than the order of the column?

Or am I missing something entirely?

I'm working with SQLite3, queried by PHP 7.1

Answer (score 3):

ORDER BY with LIMIT is a little bit more efficient than a plain ORDER BY because only the first few rows need to be completely sorted.

Anyway, for a single-column index, the sort order (ASC or DESC) is pointless because SQLite can step through an index either forwards or backwards.

Indexes are used automatically when SQLite estimates that they would be useful.
To check what actually happens, run [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) (or set `.eqp on` in the `sqlite3` shell).